# Shake Gesture To Random Table View Cell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am currently working on update 3 to my app, I wanted to add the ability to shake the iPhone and have it go to a random cell in my UITableView. I know Apple recommends against doing this kind of gesture, but I want to add it or at least try it out.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
-(void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
       if(motion == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake)
       {
          NSLog(@"Shake");
       }
}
-(BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder
{
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Need to set view/controller as firstResponder by calling `-becomeFirstResponder` method and also implement `canBecomeFirstResponder` method and return `YES` to respond to shake event.